# Updating Widget Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

In my widget, I have a refresh button that I use to tell the (custom) listview the dataset has changed. Right now, I have my onRecieve callback being called when the refresh button is clicked, but the intent bundle being passed is null so I can't call onUpdate on the IDs.

I checked in the function where I add the extras, It says the integer array it's adding is of length 1 and non null, I'm not sure why this isn't working :/ Hopefully someone here can give me a hand.

Thanks.

**WidgetProvider.java**

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        super.onDeleted(context, appWidgetIds);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context)
    {
        super.onDisabled(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context)
    {
        super.onEnabled(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        System.out.println("RECIEVED SOMETHING:" + intent.getAction());
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetMgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        int[] ids = extras.getIntArray(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS); //NPE ON THIS LINE, EXTRAS IS NULL

        System.out.println("SENDING AN UPDATE");
        onUpdate(context, appWidgetMgr, ids);

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action, int[] ids) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
        System.out.println("PUTTING ARRAY OF LEN: " + ids.length);
        intent.setAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<appWidgetIds.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("CHECK");
            RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.app_widget);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    appWidgetIds[i]);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

            rv.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.list, intent);

            rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.refresh, getPendingSelfIntent(context,
                    "refresh", appWidgetIds));

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], rv);
        }
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

Edit: New onRecieve function, same error:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if("refresh".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            System.out.println("RECIEVED SOMETHING:" + intent.getAction());
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetMgr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            int[] ids = extras.getIntArray(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

            System.out.println("SENDING AN UPDATE");
            onUpdate(context, appWidgetMgr, ids);
        }

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source for AppWidgetProvider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.java#49), `onReceive()` is called first for every standard widget operation, not just for your custom code. You should wrap your code in an if check that ensures that it is your button that was pressed.

```
// In onReceive()
if ("refresh".equals(intent.getAction())) {
  // Do your code
}
```

You'll also note from the [PendingIntent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html):

> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent. A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents, expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. If you use two Intent objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will get the same PendingIntent for both of them.
>
> ...
>
> If you only need one PendingIntent active at a time for any of the Intents you will use, then you can alternatively use the flags FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to either cancel or modify whatever current PendingIntent is associated with the Intent you are supplying.

So you should also update your call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` to

```
return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent,
  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Of course, an alternative would to just call [AppWidgetManager#getAppWidgetIds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#getAppWidgetIds(android.content.ComponentName)) and skip setting any extras at all.

Comment: Updated my answer: I don't even think you need to set any extras at all, now that I look at what you're doing again.

Comment: Interesting snippet, didn't know that. Either adjusting my PendingIntent or using getAppWidgetIds will solve the problem. Cheers :)

Comment: @Nathan, did it help? I am having same problem and it doesnt help.